# android:json parsing to decode

Tags: android, json

I am making an app in which i am getting a  string as response from server side. that response is encoded in json. Now my problem is  How to do json parsing of the encoded response  from server side to decode it..
 I am geting the following response from server

["ekjyot@emobx.com","prince6179@gmail.com","facebook_514728069"]

It is in the form of an array.I want to decde it and display as textviws in my another activity.
I am using the following code:

```
                          HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String getURL =      "http://www.ondamove.it/English/mob/profile_friends.php?email="+Login.eMailId+"";
               HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
              HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
              HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity(); 


            if (resEntityGet != null) 
            {  

            String  s = EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet);
            System.out.println(s);


            JSONArray ids = new JSONArray(s);

            for(int i=0; i< ids.length(); i++){
                   System.out.println(ids[]); //print each of the   string in json array.
            }
```

but it is giving me the error : 
The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to JSONArray

how to resolve this issue.
can anyone help me over this?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JSONTokener to parse JSON documents for example:

```
String json = "{"
         + "  \"query\": \"Pizza\", "
         + "  \"locations\": [ 94043, 90210 ] "
         + "}";

 JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(json).nextValue();
 String query = object.getString("query");
 JSONArray locations = object.getJSONArray("locations");
```

Comment: How can i do this i am getting respone from server side and i waNT TO PARSE THAT

Comment: You have to get the server response as a String object "String jsonResponseString = Sever.getResponse();" then you can parse as described above.

Answer (score 1):

get your response as string

```
String jsonResponseString = Sever.getResponse();

JSONArray ids = new JSONArray(jsonResponseString);

for(int i=0; i< ids.length(); i++){
       Log.i(TAG, ids[i]); //print each of the string in json array.
}
```

Comment: ur code is giving folowing  error :  The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to JSONArray

Comment: the response you are getting is not json. it should start with a '{' . can you please check this out.

Comment: can you post the value that you are getting in String "s". i would like to see if it is json.

Comment: ["ekjyot@emobx.com","prince6179@gmail.com","facebook_514728069"] is the value that i am getting from server side

Comment: then it is not json. either send a valid json from the server, or use string functions to manipulate the string output.

Comment: tis is the only response i gt from server side.. how to separate all the emails and display on other activity ..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4090/discussion-between-ekjyot-and-yashwanth-kumar)

Answer (score 0):

[GSON](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Primitives-Examples) if you just want to keep it simple. [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) streaming if you need raw speed.

Or you could always use the built in JSON [tools](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/) -- but I'd recommend one of these other two.